# Google Chrome pinned tab highlight unread

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extension

In google chrome there is a feature that highlights pinned tabs which have unread content. For example, I pinned my Facebook page, and if any Notification or Message arrives, the pinned tab gets highlighted. This is not so noticeable as only a little white spot, sliding from right to left on the top of the tab, appears.

I want to find/create an add-on which changes the color of the "highlighted" tab to a more flashy one.

First I tried to search for an existing extension, but I haven't found any.

Help me to create this add-on.

Comment: Help me _please_.

Comment: I started a feature request on the official Chrome forum here: https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/chrome/4Dv2Rgo6skM/discussion Please vote on it so we can get it noticed. I really need this feature and it's one of the reasons I'm still using FireFox for the majority of my browsing.

Comment: Thanks for closing it, though, Will. Very helpful. Enjoy those free rep. points for not helping ;) hehe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change your theme ([here](https://tools.google.com/chrome/intl/en-GB/themes/google.html)) so the existing highlight is more obvious. It's a white glow, so you could (for example) use the 'Greyscale' theme.

I tried it and it is better; though a background flash / colour change would be much better than the light highlight IMHO.

Comment: Completely off topic; though really helpful. Couldn't find a better solution anywhere else.

Comment: @Math don't get me started on how crazy it is that threads containing useful information is constantly closed on this site.

Comment: And now I can't fix the grammar in my comment because of the 5 minute rule. Should read: 'threads containing useful information ARE constantly closed on this site.' ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help with the theme tip, BUT there is no better solution yet? The question was made long ago. There must be now something to accomplisg this, or is not? Thanks

Comment: No. Google's answer: "It's free, shut up."

Answer (score 32):

This glow notification effect happens when the tab's title is changed.

To see, create an HTML file with some Javascript that changes its title after a moment, like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.document.title = "New title!";
}, 3000);
```

Open it, pin it, then change to a different tab. After the 3 seconds, the pinned tab should glow.

Firefox 4 also does this.

---

Oh, actually read what you were trying to do now. Don't think you can change the colour, no.

Comment: I just tried this and nothing happened; do I need to enable something for this feature? I'm on Chrome dev 12.0.742.12.

Comment: first pin the tab (right click > pin) and then run the code and fast switch to an another tab. than you will see it.

Comment: @MicheldeRuiter Still works with Chrome 38, it's a very faint glow: http://i.imgur.com/2nFKg0n.gif

Comment: Not an answer to the question.

Comment: Useful information, but doesn't address the question at all.